# How can I pipe the output of "find" to "cd"?

Tags: pipe, find

What should I do to search for a file in list of folders and change current directory to the directory of the file?

I tried 
`find -name script.py | cd` but it did not work (not that I was expecting it to).

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 11):

`cd` doesn't read from stdin so you can't pipe a folder name into it. But you can use `"$(...)"` to use the output of a command as an argument for `cd`:

```
cd "$(find -name script.py -type f -printf '%h\n' -quit)"
```

`-printf '%h\n'` tells `find` to output only to folders that contains the files.

`-quit` tells `find` to quit after it found the first matching file.

Comment: neat. thanks a lot! Using this with  `vim $(locate filename)`

Answer (score 5):

You can use this code :

```
cd "$(dirname "$(find / -type f -name test | head -1)")"
```

Where as you can see it will search from the top of root directory with command `find /` , then , it will list out regular files called test -`name test` , last it will change to its directory .

Note : The piping through `head -1` will filter out all but the first.

`dirname` - strip non-directory suffix from file name

`cd` change directory